# Has there ever been a question that was migrated to SO from Meta?

Tags: discussion, migration

This is a kind of a silly/stupid question, but thought it might be fun to ask? Has any question ever been migrated or voted to me migrated from meta to SO? It seems like there are a lot of people that are quick to say that a question belongs on meta so I was just curious if this has ever gone the opposite way.

Wouldn't blame you for downvoting or voting to close. Just thought it would be a fun question to ask. Good times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. It's [not possible to migrate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12039/provide-migration-facilities-from-meta-to-other-sites) from Meta to any other site.

Comment: Well that was quick. :)