# How people are ending asking programming questions on Meta?

Tags: discussion, meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are people asking SO questions on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27013/why-are-people-asking-so-questions-on-meta)

Regularly, some new users are posting programming questions on Meta (like for example [this recent one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49532/cross-domain-response-null-using-php)).

How is that happening?

I mean, let's forget that it's written in bold on the right: ***Is your question about the Stack Overflow engine or family of websites?*** We already know that most of people just won't care to read this area.

But how are people ending on Meta instead on the "base site"? The url is longer, it's not like if they missed a part of it. So it's not a problem of "copy/paste" or "heard it somewhere". It's as well not a matter of linking, the meta link is hardly visible on SO.

So what happens? Are there some sites redirecting to Meta instead? Some unfortunate Google searches which are pointing to it?

Do we have some data which could indicate from where these people are coming?

Comment: It would really help if we could migrate these questions off meta and onto the proper site.

Comment: Take Meta for what it is. A blackhole. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12039/provide-migration-facilities-from-meta-to-other-sites

Comment: @ran - hmm, couldn't find the duplicate in search. Guess I used wrong expression. But still no answer, and no data available, though.

Comment: "the meta link is hardly visible on SO" except it's on every questions/ask page :)

Comment: @Jeff - I meant that it is present, but seriously, what can push someone who would already be on SO to click on a bottom link saying "meta", to ask his programming question? It's not like if it was a top link with a confusing title.

Comment: @Jeff - oh, my bad, it's actually in the "ask question" right text. I obviously can't read this text. But even, if someone is already about to ask on SO, why would he click this link?

Comment: @Jeff - If considering that this link is a cause, here is a [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49537/minor-change-in-the-ask-on-meta-recommendation-on-the-right-of-the-ask-questio) about it