# When composing a question, suggest posting to meta when mentioning "stackoverflow"

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, asking-questions

We're still seeing several questions a day being erroneously posted on Stack Overflow when they should be posted on meta.  Since there are heuristics for detecting and fending off subjective questions, can we do the same for questions that are about Stack Overflow itself?

One could simply search for /stack ?overflow/i in the title, body and tags, and if there are any matches, pop up "Hey! If this question is about the Stack Overflow family of sites, and not about a stack overflow exception in your program, please post this question on http://meta.stackoverflow.com instead!"

Comment: +1 because you remembered to include the "...and not about a stack overflow exception in your program..."

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a bit problematic if only because there are, in fact, questions about stack overflow exceptions. And trying to catch only the ones that refer to the site (which is not too easy) will be difficult, while just catching all of them will be very bothersome. Also, I've always been against things that assume my meaning by what I type. I rather loathe the subjective warning since it really just checks for things like the word "you", it limits how I can title non-subjective questions.

I find that Gnoupi's suggestion [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49537/minor-change-in-the-ask-on-meta-recommendation-on-the-right-of-the-ask-questio) is more likely to solve this issue. This would more clearly identify the place for questions about the Stack Overflow website, while not being in your face with mere assumptions. And judging by the nature of said suggestion, I think it's safe to assume that there are people who do look at that sidebar.