# Fix the polluted browsing for stack overflows by tag

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

I consider this question to be (in spirit) a duplicate of this other post:

[Remove tag synonym [stack-overflow] -> [stackoverflow]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60350/remove-tag-synonym-stack-overflow-stackoverflow)

...unfortunately the bounty I opened on that ended without having drawn any additional attention.  Thus, I won't be trying that bump method again. :-/

**LET ME BE CLEAR**: I am not proposing a different course of action than the one given by the person who posted that question.  I want the same thing: for the existing questions tagged `[stackoverflow]` to be reset to `[stack-overflow]` (that's for the computer science phenomenon). Then repurpose `[stackoverflow]` as a synonym for `[stackoverflow.com]` to be monitored for migration to meta.

However, I'm pointing specifically to the user experience of tag searches right now, which is bad...

---

My motivation actually came from searching for tags about stack overflows, using the tag whose description says it's the official tag for the CS concept ([stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow)).  It is generally a cue for migration, and things that have been migrated show up in tag browsing in the tag list...without the ability to remove or edit it.

My preference is for tags that have hyphens in them; I like `linked-list` better than `linkedlist` for instance.  So `stack-overflow` works for me for me...and I agree with this post that the conventions should be mapped out clearly in general:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75155/tag-synonym-improvement

Leaving [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) for people to monitor for migration seems useful...as is making it synonym for the existing [stackoverflow.com](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow.com).  There's a [stackoverflow-api](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow-api) too.

Comment: Wait, I'm confused. What is it you want to have happen?

Comment: @Nightfirecat I want the existing questions tagged [stackoverflow] to be reset to [stack-overflow], that's for the computer science phenomenon.  Then leave [stackoverflow] behind and set it to be a synonym for [stackoverflow.com].  (I essentially agree with the reasoning of the poster of the other question regarding it being better for monitoring meta migrations.  I've only added that the current situation of browsing looking for questions about actual call-stack overflows is not acceptable due to constant appearance of new entries at the top plus tag-uneditable "migrated" questions...)