# Use the new helpcenter for the question/answer ban message

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, post-ban, help-center

> Related: ["We're no longer accepting" message should not be hosted on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124231/were-no-longer-accepting-message-should-not-be-hosted-on-meta)

The helpcenter has [an entry for the question ban message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/question-bans). It still links to the [meta page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers/86998#86998) for further details. Besides that, the question ban message [still links to the old page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183282/there-was-a-confusion-and-my-account-was-banned).

Now that we have the helpcenter, could the following changes be implemented?

- Link to the help center instead of the meta post
- Remove the link to the meta post from the help center, and instead incorporate its contents into the helpcenter itself

Comment: That'd also help lower the amount of posts from people who are sent to Meta because of that message in the first place.

Comment: *Yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeesssssssssssssssssssss*

Comment: A help center page makes a lot more sense as a target for the question-ban link than a question here. The Q/A structure alone isn't the easiest to parse for someone looking for a quick answer as to why they were banned and what to do about it. There's a reason why that question had to be locked after accumulating 11 bad answers, 207 deleted comments, and 42 flags.

Comment: @BradLarson: as well as spawning countless dupes and OT programming qs on meta.

Comment: @Manishearth - Shog does seem to indicate that there aren't a lot of off topic questions here related to the ban message: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177542/135615 , but if we can reduce this and provide better clarity by directing people to the help center, I'm all for it.

Comment: This is a good idea. We have a bit of a backlog regarding help center stuff at the moment, but rest assured we will get to it soon!

Comment: @Laura: Yay! You have the gratitude of Meta for years to come :)

Comment: @Laura Post that as an answer, can't bounty a comment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a Good Idea with a lot of support, so it's on our to-do list. We have quite a few little changes we're still working on, but I will update here when this one is complete.

Edit: This is <strike>status-partially-completed</strike> completed. The Help Center article has been expanded and no longer links to MSO. The link in the error messages has also been changed.

Comment: _Hands over a plateful of waffles with bacon syrup_

Comment: Just curious: is it a direct link or a `goo.gl` link? And is it clickable? (The question text of [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) might need an update.)

Comment: @Arjan: The Help Center article itself would seem to indicate that it's a direct link, based on the message that's quoted there: http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

Comment: Indeed, @BoltClock, and if true then I still wonder why earlier [requests to make it a clickable non-Google link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91459/remove-the-shortened-url-from-the-post-ban-message) were rejected. ([*Public* statistics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UZKt6.png) aside, I see no real reason to use goo.gl in the first place.)

Comment: (Ah, and since you locked [that question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers), @BoltClock, you've got some editing to do... `;-)`)

Comment: @Arjan: Yep, assuming the staff don't get to it first ;)

Comment: Is this still used via goo.gl shortener?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Nope; I'm updating the MSO faq post now.

Comment: Cheers, need to retag some posts as well. :)

Comment: @Arjan: Aaaaand sure enough, [they beat me to it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/86997/revisions).

Comment: Interesting change, @BoltClock, that the "sorry" has been dropped ;-)