# Meta-Meta SO - Is letting access to all a good idea?

Tags: discussion, badges, incentive

***Edit*: I've rewritten the title to indicate I do not have a personal "opinion" on this matter, but that I'm rather trying to see where everybody stands in regards to new member participation on meta.**

I'll start by stating, in my searching, I didn't find any suggestions for this.

As I've stated outright in the title, Should access to MSO be restricted to senior members?

I actually am taking people like myself for example, who only have a few hundred rep on the main SO. Badges exist for working between the communities, but I have taken into consideration a few things.

**The generic *positive* of awarding badges on SO for use of MSO:**

**1.** More eyes, *more opinions*. **Edit: I mean opinions based on *facts***  (i.e.  i *believe* this interface/feature is dysfunctional because of

**...** There may be more, lesser prominent positives. I'd love to hear them.

**The *negatives* I see to this system:**

**1.** Any eyes, yes, but are they good eyes?

**1a.** Have these eyes seen enough?

**1b.** Are they qualified?

I know I'm not (qualified). Personally, I feel like I don't know anything about SO's infrastructure enough to contribute. Not to mention that some people posting here might not even understand duplicates and the problems they present to the community.

Hence the title, Meta-Meta SO, the only thing I'm qualified to talk about on meta.stackoverflow is the ability of talking on Meta SO.

In  other words, I really don't plan on talking here again (until I have more experience with SO).

I would love to hear extrapolations of my positives and negatives, and some conclusions people can draw (perhaps who have more experienced and have witnessed lots of good/bad content with those examples).

I do not believe this is an opinion based thread, but that facts will filter the right answer.

Comment: Fair points; on the other hand, unqualified suggestions tend to get voted away quickly. (And what George says below)

Comment: MSO is also the meta for the general SE network; do we want Cooking.SE mods who don't program banned for having no SO rep?

Comment: So being new to meta: "this question does not show any research effort: it is unclear or not useful." Is that really propagating my negatives here? I was asking a legitimate question about the structure of SO here.

Comment: Nope, not at all. Voting works differently on Meta, especially in the case of feature/change requests. In many cases, they are used to indicate agreement or disagreement with a request. In this case, one person agreed with your position, and three disagreed.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins 4*and counting. The community makes the rules, in the end.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Thanks for your good answer though.

Comment: Don't worry overmuch about the votes. My first couple of questions and answers here crashed and burned. It takes a few tries (and a lot of learning) to adjust. :) Good luck!

Comment: @GeorgeCummins I rewrote the question in an attempt to incite a different response. My question was answered, so that's all I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @jdero - I would note that there's nothing wrong with an opinion-based thread on [meta] per se.  Many of the [tag:feature-request] threads are by nature opinion-based (ie, "do you think we should do this or not").

Answer (score 16, accepted):

MSO is not just about opinions. It is also a repository of [useful documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) and a place for banned/disgruntled/new users to [request and receive clarification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19734/where-can-i-find-additional-help) regarding privileges and action consequences.

If MSO is closed to low-level users who experience problems, and they are unable resolve those problems by reading the documentation, their only recourse would be to contact the Stack Exchange team (which would usually be inefficient for both parties) or to walk away. The existence and inclusiveness of MSO allows users to find resolutions to their problems from the community when possible.

Comment: I wasn't even aware of the banned user mention. Is that really true?

Comment: @jdero Yep: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers

Comment: Has anyone ever suggested splitting meta into different parts? Do banned users even know to look to meta?

Comment: That's [no longer the case](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124231/were-no-longer-accepting-message-should-not-be-hosted-on-meta), but it certainly was before.

Comment: @Tim Thanks for pointing that out.