# How can I migrate a question from Superuser to Meta? (Or vise-versa)

Tags: support, migration

How can I migrate a question from Superuser to Meta? (Or vise-versa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jon stated, you cannot migrate the question yourself, yet.  Only 3K+ rep users can vote to migrate the question.  Your best bet would be to flag the question for moderator attention and ask the moderator to move it.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, questions can be migrated from a Trilogy site to Meta if 5 users with 3k+ reputation vote to migrate the question.

However, questions cannot be migrated from Meta back to any of the Trilogy sites. There is currently an open [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12039/provide-migration-facilities-from-meta-to-other-sites) for that facility.

With reference to [this question you asked](https://superuser.com/questions/141780/i-occasionally-get-a-message-in-superuser-that-it-works-better-with-java-script-e), the moderator closed it as off-topic instead of migrating because he realized the same question had already been asked here on Meta.