# Add Meta Stack Overflow → Stack Overflow migration path

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow, migration, meta

It seems like we've had an upswing in meta posts that actually belong on Stack Overflow (I'm not sure how that happens, but it does). I generally mod flag them, but they usually end up closing before a mod sees the flag. Is it possible to just add a migration path from Meta Stack Overflow to Stack Overflow?

Comment: This would appear to be completed now in spite of Jeff's rejection of it :)  (see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93345/convert-android-code-to-monoandroid-code?noredirect=1 )

Comment: @Daniel Mods can migrate anywhere; I wanted a migration path so 3k users here could vote to migrate

Comment: As per @DanielDiPaolo's comment, should this question have the tag [status-accepted]?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, I don't support this.

If users are so confused that they ask a programming question here, they need to figure a few things out on their own without us spoon feeding it to them.

Comment: +1.  I've only seen low-quality SO posts on meta.SO, never good ones.

Answer (score 6):

As I posted [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12039/provide-migration-facilities-from-meta-to-other-sites/65860#65860) (which was written before mods had the facility to migrate anywhere in the network):

> With the per-site-Meta model now, I
>   think the following makes the most
>   sense:
>
> - On all Meta sites, allow migration to the parent site
> - On per-site Metas, also allow migration to Meta Stack Overflow
>
> This makes Meta SO an endpoint for
>   Meta questions (as it should be), but
>   allows a Meta site to migrate back and
>   forth between the parent site (and
>   that's it -- no MSO to SU, for
>   example).

Under the new modified system, this scheme still works, and would alleviate moderators from having to intervene to do a migration. The 3k+ rep users on Meta are pretty active, and obvious programming questions do get closed quickly. On other per-site-Metas, there's nothing wrong with having this ability as well, though it's probably more likely that a mod will come along first before migration quorum is reached.

I should point out that contrary to what Jeff said in his answer here, programming questions on Meta *are actively being migrated by moderators to the parent site* (at least some of them). So if what Jeff said is what should happen, then mods need to stop "spoon-feeding" the users. Or, of course, the site close/migration policy could be changed so regular users do the work *for* the mods...

Answer (score 2):

Diamond moderators can already migrate between any site, including from Meta to Stack Overflow. Simply flag the question for migration and it will be so. This can also be done if the question was already closed.

Comment: When I said "I generally mod flag them, but they usually end up closing before a mod sees the flag", I meant I mod flag them with "Please move to SO". Often the question closes as off-topic and the user leaves or reposts manually before a mod gets to it. If it's going to be increasingly common that we need to move to SO, we might as well have a migration path for it (it's not like meta is running out of space on the close dialog)