# Why are questions being prematurely closed and not migrated?

Tags: discussion, migration, deleted-questions

Shouldn't questions like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111891/if-i-change-resolution-of-my-desktop-then-it-will-not-affects-any-resolution-to), (was going to quote more, but they have mysteriously disappeared...) be moved on to their respective sites and re-tagged, instead of just closed outright?

The question quoted was just one example, why would an open discussion question be down-voted? Wait a sec, what would down-voting an open discussion question even say about your stance on the matter? " I disagree with this question being asked "?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it means here on meta. A downvote indicates disagreement.

Comment: Your question was, "Shouldn't questions like this be moved on to their respective sites and re-tagged, instead of just closed outright?" So you're saying they should be moved, and anyone who disagrees will downvote.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no migration path from Meta Stack Overflow to other Stack Exchange sites for user that have [enough reputation to close questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions). See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78126/add-meta-stack-overflow-stack-overflow-migration-path) for further information.

[Diamond Moderators](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/about#moderators) *can* migrate questions to any site if they choose to. I suspect that particular question was not migrated as the quality of the question is pretty poor and would have been closed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hmm, I think there should (second highest votes answer on that question.)  But that's just me I suppose, and six others.

Comment: Thank you for improving your answer to include information about diamond moderators :)

Comment: I doubt diamond mods would ever actually choose to migrate a question on meta meant for some other site. It should be _very_ clear to anyone who asks here that meta is not for such questions yet they still do. We don't need to "help" users who just don't get this any more than we already do. It's too bad we can't stop them outright. If they were paying attention at all, they would have put it in the right place themselves. They're not going to learn if we did it for them.

Answer (score 8):

> was going to quote more, but they have mysteriously disappeared...

They don't disappear "mysteriously". They are *deleted*, because they are off-topic here and distract from the real questions about Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange network (which this site is about). See [the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion):

> Questions that are extremely off topic, or of very low quality, may be removed at the discretion of the community and moderators.

You as a user (not you, cbroughton, *personally*) are expected to post the question on the site it belongs to. There's no need for a migration path back to – for example Stack Overflow. I can't imagine you don't know Stack Overflow when you manage to post on Meta Stack Overflow. Even more so, if you repeatedly post off-topic questions on Meta Stack Overflow but already know how to use Stack Overflow, why should we do you a favor and migrate it back? In many cases, people post here to evade the low quality filter. That would be a way to circumvent it.

> why would an open discussion question be down-voted?

Because people disagree with your idea of having them migrated. Voting on Meta, as you can read in [the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences),

> […] works a bit differently from other Stack Exchange sites. On Meta Stack Overflow, voting is often used to express agreement or disagreement, not to point out a lack of quality or helpfulness

So, please take a minute to read the FAQs of the sites you are planning to post a question on. This will save you from surprising downvotes, closed questions and deletions.

Answer (score 7):

No. That question appears nonsensical. And one of the golden rules of migration is "[Don't migrate crap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82941/please-dont-migrate-low-quality-questions-to-other-sites/82986#82986)".