# Seriously. A mod won't migrate?

Tags: discussion, support, migration, declined-flags

I posted two flags on this question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115179/155556

The 1st one was accepted and the 2nd one was rejected.

Here is my flag requests:[image: really?]

> declined - if the user cannot work out how to post on the proper site, migration will not make the question any better

**Really??**

We beat down newbies because they don't know any better? Why not just migrate it??

(The user has since reposted his Q: [jQuery's .position conflicts with CSS3's transform](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8420340/561731) )

Comment: I read that flag as: *"The question is not a good quality question to begin with; migrating won't make it any better."*

Comment: @RobertHarvey but that does not change whether the OP can improve their question elsewhere.

Comment: The First Commandment of Migration is "Don't Migrate Crap." The user can always repost on the correct site, and hopefully improve the question while he's at it.

Comment: Why should we care if they don't?

Comment: Did anybody else notice that "problem", just became "conflicts"? :s

Comment: @staticbeast what do you mean?

Comment: See [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78217/145982)

Comment: @MichaelMrozek lol

Comment: I was referencing this meta question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944/the-title-word-filter-is-one-of-the-worst-ideas-ever-implemented-on-so  
More particularly that the user's question on meta was ".position jquery problem" and on SO it was ".position jquery conflicts".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do users often ask blatantly off-topic questions here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305749/why-do-users-often-ask-blatantly-off-topic-questions-here-on-meta)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes really.

Meta is a black hole. You come, you read, you lose your mind.

There are two reasons programming questions are posted on Meta:

1. To get around a ban or any rate limiting in effect.
2. They have no idea where to find their pants and instead wear their socks on their ears.

In either of these cases, migration only hurts small children and faeries who enjoy a coked up sleuth who plays the fiddle. If you enjoy such molestation, feel free to request migrations for questions that also are subpar pr0blams. Expect to be denied.

You want out of Meta? That's not going to happen unless you do it yourself.

Comment: Haha. ok.  But I have seen question get migrated **out** of meta before, guess they were better written :-P

Comment: **First rule about Meta: Don't talk about Meta** :-P

Comment: In this case, the reason is #1: A ban on posting questions with "Problem" in the title.

Comment: Dunno why but your answer really makes me want to ask a programming question here. Something stupid like whats the definition of an operator.

Answer (score 21):

Yes, seriously.  We don't migrate away from Meta.  The majority of cases where programming questions gets asked here are cases where the OP is trying to get around an account ban.

> We beat down newbies because they don't know any better?

How is that beating them down?  They can just go post it on SO if they aren't banned.  I don't see the harm.

Comment: Ok. but thats not a reason to decline a flag. comment maybe. also why not migrate? that is what the feature is for (assuming the user is **not** banned)

Comment: That certainly is a reason to decline a flag. Why didn't you comment if you wanted a response as a comment?

Comment: Isn't the system supposed to block migrations which would get around bans anyway, making your "majority of cases" moot?

Comment: @Toomai Only if they have a linked account. Quite often, users just create a new account on meta and ask their question in the hopes of getting it migrated

Comment: I am not sure what you expect us to do with the flag if not decline it.

Comment: @yoda i **did** comment

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA So basically this is yet another declined flag grievance post?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ what is?

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA and you **also** flagged. You got a response [in a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115179/position-jquery-problem#comment-299913) for your comment and a response via the decline reason for your flag.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA This question; you are complaining that your flag got declined.

Comment: @yoda I did not get a response in the comments till i posted this Q

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ no im asking why it got declined. keep it declined, i don't care, im just curious as to the **why**

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Well, you didn't wait for a response via comments before you flagged either. So what did you expect?