# Throw a warning once code in question detected

Tags: feature-request, meta

This is very meta question, which has to be asked because the off-topic coding questions pop here every now and then.

Once code in question body detected, a user should be introduced to <s>the clippy saying</s> a prompt reading something like:

> It looks like your question is about coding, are you sure it's a right place to ask it? Before asking, please see the help center

To filter false positives, I'd suggest that would be shown only to low-rep users, maybe just to 1-rep users, excluding association bonus just in case.

Comment: Or maybe it's already a thing that I'm not aware of? I haven't been tracking new changes to Stack Exchange for about 1000 years.

Comment: Most users are posting on meta because they're post banned, according to the mods, so this isn't going to help anything.  They know they're in the wrong place and don't care.

Comment: @Servy, oh, okay then! I didn't take that into account.

Comment: Related: [Why do users often ask blatantly off-topic questions here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305749/why-do-users-often-ask-blatantly-off-topic-questions-here-on-meta) (cc @Servy)