# The off-topic flag window does not give you any options in meta. Why?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, options

I flagged my first off topic question here and I was just curious why there is no window with the 5 options as it is in other sites. Is it

1. because the vast majority of the off-topic questions belong to SO?
2. because somebody forgot to add the window?
3. because mods do not want to be told where those questions should go?
4. because off-topic posters get a summary execution so there's no point in migrating the question?
5. all of the above?
6. 1, 3 and 4 are correct?
7. none of the above?

Comment: You can *always* suggest a destination for a question if you want to. Just pick the "other" reason and make your plea. The radio buttons are for *common* scenarios.

Comment: Fun fact: [one user](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/160424/unknown) thought [posting on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87753/how-to-fetch-input-from-winforms-app) was a smart way to get their question onto SO, while being banned from asking questions there. ;-)

Comment: @Arjan can't blame him for trying! LOL. Some times I wonder why some people don't use the brain to do the things right from the beginning instead of figuring a way to find a hole in the system...

Comment: @Arjan, LOL! Now I know why such questions are not migrated to SO. :P

Comment: I wonder why meta thinks that the most related question is "Can we ask stupid questions here or give stupid answers?" Is it meta trying to tell me something about my questions? :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the above. There is no capacity to migrate outside of a Meta site, except by moderators. We're less [the black hole we were often originally cited as](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12039/provide-migration-facilities-from-meta-to-other-sites/58568#58568), but nevertheless it's still impossible for normal users to migrate items out of here.

As the off-topic flag mimics the off-topic vote, and the off-topic vote does not give migration options, so too does the off-topic flag not give migration options.

Comment: If someone posts on Meta when they mean to ask in SO, it should stay the black hole. Reading comprehension clearly isn't there and any migrations out are only added to the junk pile.

Comment: OK, I get it's intentional, but what is the rationale for not allowing migrations from here? In the link you provided I found reasons to allow migration, rather than reasons to prevent them. Anyhow, your reply is almost "1, 3 and 4 are correct" ;)

Comment: @random as usual, if the question is bad, then it will be closed, not migrated. But the same "reading comprehension" requirement could be applied to most of the off-topic questions either here on in SO.

Comment: @Aleadam It's probably because during the early times of Meta Stack Overflow, there indeed was little to no reason or need for question to be migrated out of the site, since it was meta-discussion unlike what anything in the Trilogy handled. Also, 1, 3, and 4 are all entirely incorrect - 3, for example, I often flag questions on Meta for migration and I've not gotten scolded for it.

Comment: Even if the question was nicely formatted and asked well, what's the point of migrating out of Meta when they don't even know where to ask? SO is not for want of new questions @ale

Comment: @Grace so the reason is mostly historical? And please, do not take seriously the options 3 and 4! They were meant as a joke, but if you find them offensive in any way please let me know and I will remove them from the question.

Comment: @Aleadam I don't take them offensive, but when I answer with "None of the above", it still means "None of the above". ♪

Comment: @Aleadam, even if the user searched SO proper and then somehow accidentally hit the Ask Question button on MSO: while tagging the question alarm bells should ring. Why on earth would any of the mandatory MSO tags `[support]`, `[discussion]`, `[bug]` or `[feature-request]` be relevant on SO?

Comment: @random I still don't get how an off-topic question here is more off-topic than a question anywhere else. But, I guess the question is answered already: there are no options because there is no migration path, and that's by design, whatever the reasons are.